# Copy String from specific index dynamically in C

Tags: c, strncpy

if i have

```
 char str_cp[50],str[50], str_other[50], str_type[50];
 strcpy(str,"how are you : i am fine");
 strcpy(str_other, "who are you : may be robot or human being");
 strcpy(str_type,"type   : worker / manager ");
```

so how to code... to copy a string from ":" to end of the line? when i am not known with 
the end index.

Comment: A good start might be to [find the separator character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Comment: What do you mean by "the end index"? Aren't you copying all the way to the end of the string?

Comment: end index mean... the last character of the line.

Comment: yes i want to copy from ": " till end of line

Comment: @FaisalHameed check my answer upvote and accept it if you find this helpful

Comment: Note that the assignments shown are invalid C code.  It isn't hard to make them into valid initializers, but you, the OP, should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, copying from a specific character on, to the end of the string, can be accomplished with `strcpy`, assuming that you have a buffer that is sufficiently large. All you need to do is passing the pointer to the initial character that you want to keep.

The pointer can be found with [`strchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchrnul.3.html), like this:

```
const char *tail = strchr(str, ':') + 1; // skip ':' itself. Add 2 to skip ' ' too
```

If you print `tail`, you will get the content of the remainder of the string:

```
printf("%s\n", tail);
```

If you need a copy, make it with `strcpy`:

```
size_t len = strlen(tail)+1;
char *copy = malloc(len);
strcpy(copy, tail);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a different array of size 50 and then just copy

```
char source[150]; // supoose your sorce array
char dest[150];   // suppose your destination
int i =0,Flag =0,j=0;

for(char c = source[i];c != '\0';i++)
 {  if(c == ':') 
       Flag = 1; // coz we have to start copying from here

    if(Flag == 1)
      dest[j++]=c; //copying the elements
  }
```

Comment: Can we edit it to omit Flag, as  if(c == ':' || strlen(dest) > 0){ dest[j++]=c; }

Comment: yes it can work but performance will decrease @vijaymishra upvote if you find this helpful thanks

Comment: Bcoz That one is short and without loop. i even vote u up. thanks

Comment: A solution for copying strings without pointers. Less headaches. Thanks you. I think that, on different sizes, you could need to null-terminate the `dest` variable. Something like `dest[j]='\0'`outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct string String; //do we suppose you wrote a string buffer
// to avoid mallloc and reallock 
char * d_prs(String * buf; char * to_parse)
{
     reset_st(buf);// do you suppose you have a macro to reset the buffer
     while(*to_parse)
        if(*to_parse++==':') break;
     if(!*to_parse)return NULL;  //if null the str, does not contain ':'
     concat_s(buf,to_parse); //the pointer is right initalized...justcpy
     return str_toCstring(buf);//a macro to get the data of the buffer    

}
```